# What does object.__str__ and object.__repr__ do? Warning: It's not the same as Class.__str__ and Class.__repr__

Tags: python, function, class, oop

```
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def __str__(self):
        return 'You have called __str__'
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'You have called __repr__'

a = TestClass()
print(object.__repr__(a))
print(object.__str__(a))
```

**Output:**

```
<__main__.TestClass object at 0x7fe175c547c0>
You have called __repr__
```

---

What does those two functions do?

---

My understanding is that calling `str(a)` returns `a.__str__()` and calling `repr(a)` returns `a.__repr__()`. `print(a)` also prints the string, `a.__str__()` since there is an implicit `str(a)` conversion going on.

**Note that my question is not a duplicate to another popular question; see my first comment below.**

The behaviour is COUNTERINTUITIVE; doing `print(object.__str__(a))` prints the repr string instead of the str string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between \_\_str\_\_ and \_\_repr\_\_?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/what-is-the-difference-between-str-and-repr)

Comment: @0x263A It's different. It's not asking about `TestClass.__str__(a)`, but rather `object.__str__(a)`. Similarly, with the `__repr__` thing. In fact, the behavior is counterintuitive; `object.__str__(a)` prints the repr string and not the str string.

Comment: There's probably an answer here, but `object.__str__(a)` is not something you should ever sensibly do to begin with…

Comment: @deceze I am reading a book (Think Python); it uses that in one of the .py files linked in the book.

Comment: That's not… typical…

Comment: Shouldn't the output of `object.__str__(a)` be "You have called `__repr__`" in this example?

Comment: @0x263A Yes, I did say that.

Comment: @Adola in other words, your provided output does not match the actual output

Comment: @0x263A It matched. I tried copy-pasting and running the code in `www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/`, and the output is essentially the same. Maybe, you've misread.

Comment: `return 'You have called __repr__'` cannot produce the output "This is a repr string", and there's nowhere else this output could come from.

Comment: Sorry, it was a tiny mistake.

Comment: It seems your question has been answered but that site you provided outputs, "You have called __repr__" (as expected) you provided the output: "This is a repr string". Those are very different outputs. The reason this matters is because you stated you were using a book to learn and I was curious if the authors of the book had altered some function/if your question was perhaps missing a piece of information.

Comment: @deceze If you're interested about the usage in the book see https://github.com/AllenDowney/ThinkPython2/blob/master/code/BadKangaroo.py and https://github.com/AllenDowney/ThinkPython2/blob/master/code/GoodKangaroo.py

Comment: *"WARNING: this program contains a NASTY bug.  I put
it there on purpose as a debugging exercise, but
you DO NOT want to emulate this example!"*…?

Comment: @deceze There are two links, the first is the buggy one and the second is the correct one. The bug is using a mutable type (list) as an optional argument which is potentially dangerous. It's irrelevant to the question here. :)

Comment: `object.__str__` is probably used there explicitly in order to avoid an infinite recursion in the string printing, which would also give away the actual bug and/or simply crash the program…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `object` class provides default implementations for the `__repr__` and `__str__` methods.

- `object.__repr__` displays the type of the object and its `id` (the address of the object in CPython)
- `object.__str__(a)` calls `repr(a)`. The rationale is that if `__str__` is not overriden in a class `str(a)` will automatically call `repr(a)`, *using a possible override of `__repr__`*. More exactly, the official documentation of the Python Language Reference / Data Model / Special method names / Basic customization says:

  > `object.__str__(self)`
  >
  > ...The default implementation defined by the built-in type object calls `object.__repr__()`.

  ... which in turn calls the overriden `__repr__` method like `repr(object)` would have done.

This is exactly what happens here because you are directly calling `object.__str__` while this is not expected.

Comment: I actually suspected this, since when the `__str__` is not defined, it will return `__repr__` instead when calling `str(a)`. Is this on the Python's official documentation? Where did you learn this?

Comment: @Adola: I have edited my answer with a reference to the official doc.